# Not able to create jar from develop branch

Tags: testing, karate

@ptrthomas

I am also facing issue of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/661

According to you,this has been fixed in version '1.0.0' in develop branch.

I am not able to create the jar from develop branch (As I am following these steps:-https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide)

Please push this fix to master and release the new version or tell me how to create jar.

What I did is:-

1. git clone https://github.com/intuit/karate.git
2. cd karate
3. git checkout develop
4. mvn clean install -P pre-release

After this I am getting this error:-

```
10:53:42.068 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.XmlUtilsTest - map: {env:Envelope={_={env:Header=null, env:Body={_={QueryUsageBalanceResponse={_={Balance=null, Result={Success=null, Error={Category=DAT, Code=DAT_USAGE_1003, Description=Invalid Request: Invalid Input criteria: No asset found for license/eoc (630289335971198/855939)., Source=SIEBEL}}}, @={xmlns=http://www.intuit.com/iep/ServiceUsage/IntuitServiceUsageABO/V1}}}, @={xmlns=http://www.intuit.com/iep/ServiceUsage/IntuitServiceUsageABO/V1}}}, @={xmlns:S=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, xmlns:env=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}}}
[INFO] Tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 s - in com.intuit.karate.XmlUtilsTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   RunnerTest.testRunningFeatureFromJavaApi:92 expected:<someValue> but was:<null>
[ERROR]   RunnerTest.testRunningRelativePathFeatureFromJavaApi:100 expected:<someValue> but was:<null>
[ERROR]   
ScriptTest.testFromJsKarateGetForJsonObjectVariableAndCallFeatureAndJs:1359
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ConfigTest.testSettingVariableViaKarateConfig:21 » Runtime javascript evaluati...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 242, Failures: 3, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] karate-parent ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.342 s]
[INFO] karate-core ........................................ FAILURE [ 11.289 s]
[INFO] karate-apache ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-junit4 ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-junit5 ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-netty ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-gatling ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-demo ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-mock-servlet ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-jersey ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karate-archetype ................................... SKIPPED
```

Comment: Please add this post directly to GitHub's issue. This is not for StackOverflow, you cannot directly tag GitHub users here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CI build is green](https://travis-ci.org/intuit/karate) so it would help us if you find the root cause and let us know how to fix it.

For now please do this for step 4.

```
mvn clean install -P pre-release -DskipTests
```

Comment: Thanks a lot on adding -DskipTests,I will be able to create the jar